# Use iPhone location to update google map

Tags: html, drupal, geolocation, maps

I am building a cycle information site and want to be able to grab the users location from their iPhone so i update my Google map and provide the user with relevant information. There is a Drupal module called Geolocation which uses the HTML5 option to do this and i have found the code which it is performing the task in the module below.

```
// START: Autodetect clientlocation.
          // First use browser geolocation
          if (navigator.geolocation) {
            browserSupportFlag = true;
            $('#geolocation-help-' + i + ':not(.geolocation-processed)').addClass('geolocation-processed').append(Drupal.t(', or use your browser geolocation system by clicking this link') +': <span id="geolocation-client-location-' + i + '" class="geolocation-client-location">' + Drupal.t('My Location') + '</span>');
            // Set current user location, if available
            $('#geolocation-client-location-' + i + ':not(.geolocation-processed)').addClass('geolocation-processed').click(function() {
              navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                Drupal.Geolocation.maps[i].setCenter(latLng);
                Drupal.Geolocation.setMapMarker(latLng, i);
                Drupal.Geolocation.codeLatLng(latLng, i, 'geocoder');
              }, function() {
                Drupal.Geolocation.handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag, i);
              });
            });
          }
```

Does anybody have any Google Maps API V3 experience of implementing this or similar? I would prefer the user to have to click "My Location" or equivalent to then use their iPhone's location to update the map rather than request it automatically. This is my Map and the array of markers that i have on it. How can i utilise the iPhones location to update it?

```
function initialize() {

  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.51251523, -0.133201961),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

  var bikeLayer = new google.maps.BicyclingLayer();
  bikeLayer.setMap(map);

  setMarkers(map, spots);
}


var spots = [

['Marylebone', 51.51811784, -0.144228881, '2.png', 2901, 'Broadcasting House - Marylebone</br>Available Bikes: 1</br>Number of Docks: 13</br> View more information about <a href="/node/2901">this dock</a>'],


['Fitzrovia', 51.51991453, -0.136039674, '3.png', 2908, 'Scala Street - Fitzrovia</br>Available Bikes: 8</br>Number of Docks: 21</br> View more information about <a href="/node/2908">this dock</a>'],


['Fitzrovia', 51.52351808, -0.143613641, '3.png', 2923, 'Bolsover Street - Fitzrovia</br>Available Bikes: 6</br>Number of Docks: 19</br> View more information about <a href="/node/2923">this dock</a>'],


['Fitzrovia', 51.52025302, -0.141327271, '3.png', 2975, 'Great Titchfield Street - Fitzrovia</br>Available Bikes: 5</br>Number of Docks: 19</br> View more information about <a href="/node/2975">this dock</a>'],


['Bloomsbury', 51.51858757, -0.132053392, '3.png', 2982, 'Bayley Street  - Bloomsbury</br>Available Bikes: 12</br>Number of Docks: 25</br> View more information about <a href="/node/2982">this dock</a>']

];

function setMarkers(map, locations) {

      var image1 = new google.maps.MarkerImage('amber-spot.png',
      new google.maps.Size(30, 36),
      new google.maps.Point(0,0),
      new google.maps.Point(0, 32));

  var shape = {
      coord: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18 , 1],
      type: 'poly'
  };
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();  
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var spot = locations[i];
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(spot[1], spot[2]);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        icon: spot[3],
        title: spot[0],
        zIndex: spot[4],
        html: spot[5]
    });
    bounds.extend(myLatLng);
    map.fitBounds(bounds);  
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
});

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(this.html);
    infowindow.open(map,this);
});
  }
}
```

thanks

Lee

Comment: To clarify: you want the user to hop on your site with the map, click show my location, then you will save their location, and then relocate the map window to their location?

Answer (score 1):

First you will need a javascript function that will be fired from a button press, or a link click. This function will use the geolocation api available through html5 to check if the user can provide you with their location and grab it if so. The remainder of the function will use the google maps api to pan to that lat lng coordinate and set the zoom level appropriately.

Here is the google maps api map object which has the methods you need:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map

And this site has a great overview of basically everything you are trying to do:
http://www.html5laboratory.com/geolocation.php

Finally don't forget to save the location in your database or client side javascript array. If you are saving the data, warn the user of that for privacy implications.